# Parse.com exported data missing _Schema

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-dashboard

Hi exported my app before parse.com was shutdown and I saw some JSONs so i though it is OK. Today I tried to import these data to mongo only to find out that I need _Schema file import too but it is missing from the exported file.

Is there a way how to generate this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `_SCHEMA` collection of my local Parse Server installation it seems fairly easy to reconstruct manually. It only contains the columns and their types for each collection with the collection name being the object id.

Below is an example of the `_SCHEMA` entry for my `_User` collection
[image: Example Schema]

Comment: you were right, I created manually those Classes via parse-dashboard and specify the Column names and types and then the import was working